DAX Measure for value for earliest, selected and previous two quarters from table
I have a table that contains a value at the end of each quarter categorized by ID. I want to create a DAX measure that gives me the earliest value, the current value, and the value for the two previous quarters.
I've added a screenshot below of how my table could look.
So, using a slicer for YearQuarter from my date table and a slicer for ID, I select ID = 1 and YearQuarter = 2024 Q1 I the output table should look like:



YearQuarter
ID
Value




2022 Q1
1
43


2023 Q3
1
11


2023 Q4
1
59


2024 Q1
1
14



Preferably, the number of previous quarters shown should be easily changable (more nice to have, than must have).

